# Binary Search algorithm query

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to revise Computer Science using the Specimen paper I did in December mocks but I dont understand how the answer from the markscheme was reached.

The link to the paper and markscheme is here: [http://www.aqa.org.uk/subjects/compu...ment-resources](https://www.aqa.org.uk/subjects/computer-science-and-it/gcse/computer-science-8520/assessment-resources)

The question I dont understand is question 4.1 on page 8 which asks you to: Complete the trace table for the binary search algorithm.

I do not understand why in the first line of the trace table, the mid is 3 and not 3.5 in the markscheme and why the arr[mid] is 13.

Could someone help please? I was not aware that there was any weird rule about rounding down rather than up in a binary search.

Thanks,
Confused :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  In particular, your question must be self-sufficient; no external links whose change would invalidate your question.

Comment: In many pseudocodes operator div it's not the same thing as operator /.
Here 5 div 2 = 2, and 5/2 = 2.5. Sooo (left + right) div 2 == floor((left + right) /2)

Comment: And the arr[mid] == 13, because mid = floor ((1 + 6)/2) = 3, and the arr indexing starts at 1 so (arr[1] = 3, arr[2] = 5, arr[3] = 13), so arr[3] = 13, so arr[mid] = 13, because mid = 3 :)